# Which TPM version?

Tags: command-line, tpm

What Terminal command I should make in Ubuntu in order to find out which TPM version I have, i.e TPM version 1.2 or 2.0 ?

Answer (score 4):

As [FedonKadifeli](https://askubuntu.com/users/855322/fedonkadifeli) commented, you could use the `tpm_version` program from the `tpm-tools` package.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently running Xubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and just barely added TPM to my motherboard.  The TPM version info can also be pulled from the `/sys/class/../device/..` by cat'ing the firmware_node description (referencing this deleted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1415651/231142)).

```
$ cat /sys/class/tpm/tpm0/device/firmware_node/description 
TPM 1.2 Device
```

Answer (score 0):

Another command works well also:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i tpm | grep -i Reserving
```

will result in:

```
[    0.007734] ACPI: Reserving TPM2 table memory at [mem 0x41ac6000-0x41ac604b]
```